# problem in importing java class in jsp

Tags: java, import, package

i have created a java package in source packages in netbeans

i have a jsp file in a web folder

now i want to import this java package in jsp file but i am not getting my package name in import command

Comment: Is there any error in your .java source file?

Answer (score 6):

Import package,

```
<%@ page language="java" import="yourpackage.subpackage.*,java.util.*" %>
```

or,

```
<%
 yourpackage.subpackage.ClassName k=new yourpackage.subpackage.ClassName();
 ....
%>
```