# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: import cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, import

The following is my code in a jsp file :

```
int s_id = session.getAttribute("s_id") != null ? ((Integer)     session.getAttribute("s_id")).intValue() : 0 ;
String Pending = "Pending";
%>
<!-- <jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "Shop" /> -->
<%
Shop s = new Shop();
int g_orderQuantity=0;
```

ERROR :

```
HTTP Status 500 - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from     fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /ShopViewOrder.jsp
Shop cannot be resolved to a type
line 30 : <!-- <jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "Shop" /> -->

An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /ShopViewOrder.jsp
Shop cannot be resolved to a type
line 32 : Shop s = new Shop();
```

Some answers as on page : ["Import cannot be resolved" with JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755588/import-cannot-be-resolved-with-jsp)
suggest using page import directive as follows : 
    `<%@ page import="pkgname.Class1"%>`
where they sat that you must give a fully qualified name of the class.

I have placed my Shop Class as follows : C:\Users\Documents\ShopSystem-AWSJavaWebProject\src\myPackage\Shop.java
And now I am trying to use the following syntax : 
    `<%@ page import="myPackage.Shop"%>`
But this is not working either... It gives an error saying that import myPackage cannot be resolved!

Then as per the solution mentioned in : [Eclipse is not importing classes in jsp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247116/eclipse-is-not-importing-classes-in-jsp-files)
I have ensured that the **Preferences->import->Web->Jsp Files->Editor->Content assist->Add_import_instead_of_qualified_name** is enabled
now when i use the above line : `<%@ page import="myPackage.Shop"%>`
I get the following error now :

```
exception : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 16 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. myPackage.Shop resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /ShopViewOrder.jsp
Shop cannot be resolved to a type
line 31: <!-- <jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "Shop" /> -->

An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /ShopViewOrder.jsp
Shop cannot be resolved to a type
line 33 : Shop s = new Shop();
```

Another page : [problem in importing java class in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294321/problem-in-importing-java-class-in-jsp) 
suggested `<%@ page language="java" import="yourpackage.subpackage.*,java.util.*" %>`
Hence i updated my code as :

```
<%@ page language="java" import="myPackage.Shop" %>
```

but the error still remains the same!

I have even tried the following :

```
<%@ page language="java" import="myPackage.Shop" session="true"%>
```

as suggested on [To import class to JSP in Tomcat6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172244/to-import-class-to-jsp-in-tomcat6)
yet no change in error definition!

On another site it said create a public constructor of the class you want to load.
I don't know how that helps nut I've even tried that that too doesn't work!

Please help...

As asked m adding snippets of my entire code :

```
int s_id = session.getAttribute("s_id") != null ? ((Integer) session.getAttribute("s_id")).intValue() : 0 ;
String Pending = "Pending";
<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "myPackage.Shop" />
myPackage.Shop s = new myPackage.Shop();
int g_orderQuantity=0;
Statement stmt6 = con.createStatement();
// a shop can select values from Order table
ResultSet rs3 = stmt6.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ShopSystem.Order where s_id="+s_id+"     AND  status='"+Pending+"'");
//code to declare some Vectors
while(rs3.next())
{   
    status1.add((i),rs3.getString("status"));
    status=status1.elementAt(i);        
    // in the above way am adding ResultSet values to the vector and then copying it to string.
    //i maintains the total count of all my orders
    i++;
}
for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
{
     //checking if the order table is empty
    if((g_quantityRequired == 0)||(Cust_address.equals(null))||(email.equals(null))||((contact.equals(null)))||(total_amount == 0))
    {           %>          <br> There are no pending orders. <br>           
        <%
        %>          <form name="Back" method="post" action="ShopMenu3.jsp">
        <input type="submit" value="Back">
        </form><br><br>         <%
                }        
    // Now that the order table is not empty continue to process the order..
    int g_available=0;
    //check availability of g_id in s_id
    boolean b_availability = s.checkAvailability_perShop(s_id, g_id, g_quantityRequired);
            //if sufficient quantity is not available then place an order
    if(b_availability == false)
    {           // example, if required=50, then order is placed for 100 items
        // but if required is 150, then order is placed for 150 items
        g_orderQuantity = (100>g_quantityRequired)?100 : (g_quantityRequired+100);          
        //placing order and updating the Grocery_perShop table return the amount available of g_id in s_id
        g_available = s.placeOrder_perShop(s_id, g_id, g_orderQuantity);
    }        %> 
        New g_avaliable = <%= g_available %>. The value has been updated in the database.
    <%        //now that sufficient g_id is available with s_id, we execute the order
    //updating the Grocery_perShop table
    g_available = g_available - g_quantityRequired;
    //code to insert updated values in table

sc.close();
%>    <form name="Back" method="post" action="ShopMenu3.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="Back">
</form><br><br>
```

Comment: Note : s_id stands for shop id, and g_id stands for grocery id, all variables starting from "g" refer to the Grocery and "s" refer to the Shop

Comment: Try to avoid the use Scriplet.

Answer (score 1):

If the class you are trying to access is under the `mypackage` of the application , where you have the jsp file the following statement should work,

```
<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "mypackage.Shop" />
```

check whether you have file once you are completing the build. check under build->classes as you are using eclipse.

Comment: It says "undefined type : myPackage.Shop".  I have placed the above mentioned line just below all the other concerned import statements and above where the html tag begins

Comment: please share relevant code to make it clear, try to avoid scriplet.

Comment: oh sry yes i gt rid of the undefined type error, bt now m getting the following error : exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /ShopViewOrder.jsp(14,0) The value for the useBean class attribute myPackage.Shop is invalid.

Comment: check for the names of the bean class

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fully qualified name for class in `<jsp:useBean>`. `import` page directive is not considered by `<jsp:useBean>`

```
<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "mypackage.Shop" />
```

---

Directly from Official [Oracle Documentation - Creating and Using a JavaBeans Component](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnagx/index.html)

> The value supplied for the class attribute must be a `fully qualified class name`.
>
> Note that beans cannot be in the unnamed package. Thus the format of the value must be `package-name.class-name`.